# Loading external php file in a div with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

i am making a simple project..and i need to load data from other page in an
    index.php..and i have set time of 20sec. but its not working.. could u please 
     tell me what is wrong with the query..Thanks already..

### index.php

```
   <?php
   include 'connection.php';

   ?>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>
   My First Chat app
   </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
           <script>


        $(document).ready(function(e) {
   $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
   setInterval(function(){$('#logs').load('logs.php'); } ,2000);
 });
  </script>

   </head>
  <body>
  <center><h1>Chat Box in PHP!!</h1><br><br><br></center>
 <form name="form1">
  <center>


  <strong>Username:</strong><input type="text" name="uname"              
 style="width:200px;"><br><br>

 <strong> Message:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea name="msg"      
style="width:201px;"></textarea>
 <br>
 <a href="#" onClick="sheikh()">Send</a><br><br><br><br>
  </center>
<div id="logs">
 <br> <img src="icon.png">Loading chatlogs please wait...
 </div>

  </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

### logs.php

```
    <?php

       $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","chat");
     $sqli="SELECT * FROM `logs` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
      $result=mysqli_query($con,$sqli);
       while($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     echo "<span class='uname'>" .$res["username"]."</span>:<span                          
     class='msg'>"  .$res["message"]. "</span><br>";
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: You have not added jQuery script to your html.add this line  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` or add your jquery file.

Comment: You should at least see browser console.

Comment: im sorry what is browser console???? im actually new at these things and im unaware of most terminologies..

Comment: check [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=browser+consol&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=vhiJVZnHF9SVuATa-qO4DA#q=browser+console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add jquery js in your html code. you can use online jquery.

```
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```